# How to sort varchar id on basis integer in it using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

Testcase_id in my system are varchar and generated by trigger and I want to sort them on basis of the integer value of the varchar id . I have been so far used three queries but not working at all. I have also tried with the function which converts string to integer. Here I am mentioning that function also and my query well in this query i have not used function.

```
select t.Testcase_id, 
       CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('t.Testcase_id','_',2),UNSIGNED INTEGER) as num 
from testcase_master t 
order by num
```

output(of query):

[image: Query result set]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `-1` instead of `2` inside `SUBSTRING_INDEX`:

```
select t.Testcase_id,      
       CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.Testcase_id,'_', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) as num 
from testcase_master t 
order by num
```

According to the [**manual**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

> Returns the substring from string str **before** count occurrences of the
>   delimiter delim. If count is *positive*, everything to the *left* of the
>   final delimiter (counting from the *left*) is returned. If count is
>   *negative*, everything to the *right* of the final delimiter (counting
>   from the *right*) is returned.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05b2f/8)

Comment: thank you so much you have made my day ....if you wish you can approve my question

Comment: not working in my code bro ...it is working from the database side but not working in a my project file please help me .....thanks in advance you can view the query i am facing at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1rpCWtUcfePNFJKQ1dlZFp0bGs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @yogidoshi What do you mean by *not working in a my project file*? How are you issuing the sql command to the db server?

Comment: there was issue with datatables by default sorting was done so I just removed default sorting now it is working... Thanks bro....

Answer (score 0):

use Cast

```
CAST(col AS UNSIGNED)
```

or `REPLACE` with `CAST`

```
CAST(REPLACE(testcase_id,'TC_CTU_','') AS UNSIGNED)
```

Your query :-

```
select t.Testcase_id, 
       CAST(REPLACE(testcase_id,'TC_CTU_','') AS UNSIGNED) as num 
from testcase_master t 
order by num
```

Comment: select t.Testcase_id,CAST(t.`Testcase_id` as UNSIGNED) as num from testcase_master t order by num... I have tried earlier and also tried now but it result out the same

Comment: CAST(REPLACE(testcase_id,'TC_CTU_','') AS UNSIGNED)

Comment: select t.Testcase_id, 
       CAST(REPLACE(testcase_id,'TC_CTU_','') AS UNSIGNED) as num 
from testcase_master t 
order by num

Comment: try this query @yogidoshi

Comment: great this works but every time id changes like TC_CTU and TC_MTU and so on